# Use awk towards line variable

Tags: variables, awk

Just running a fairly simple script, but got errors, and I think probably it's the problem with use awk towards variables. Maybe I miss some basic lessons about awk
Look at below:

```
#!/bin/bash
for((c=1;c<=542;c++))
do
    LINE=`head -$c FM_DEL_50r.bed|tail -1`
        cat $LINE|awk '{print $1" "$2" "$3}'

done
```

FM_DEL_50r.bed looks like:

```
chr1    3392391 3658426 DEL chr1    3392364 3658425 DEL
chr1    4011952 4392064 DEL chr1    4011953 4392062 DEL
chr1    4468526 4665322 DEL chr1    4468523 4665322 DEL
chr1    5759839 5997664 DEL chr1    5759836 5997664 DEL
```

Error is like:

```
cat: chr1: No such file or directory
cat: 3392391: No such file or directory
cat: 3658426: No such file or directory
cat: DEL: No such file or directory
cat: chr1: No such file or directory
cat: 3392364: No such file or directory
cat: 3658425: No such file or directory
cat: DEL: No such file or directory
```

Can anyone show me what's the problem?
thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this properly in bash:

```
count=0
while read a b c rest_of_line; do
  echo $a $b $c
  (( ++count == 542 )) && break
done < FM_DEL_50r.bed
```

or perhaps

```
head -542 FM_DEL_50r.bed | while read a b c rest_of_line; do echo $a $b $c; done
```

Answer (score 1):

head and tail will give you a line from
 a file. To output such a string use "echo", cat is used to print the contents of a stream or file to stdout. That's why you get the error messages.

Anyway, what are you trying to do? Are you trying to read in file
FM_DEL_50r.bed line by line and print out columns 1, 2 and 3.
Then try:

Command:

```
awk 'NR<543{print $1 " " $2 " " $3}' x
```

Output:

```
chr1 3392391 3658426
chr1 4011952 4392064
chr1 4468526 4665322
chr1 5759839 5997664
```

Comment: Actually I'm just wondering what's the problem of the code...thx

Comment: It selects lines whose line number (`NR`) is less than 543.

Comment: Since you don't change the OFS, it is cleaner to write `print $1, $2, $3`

Answer (score 1):

Chris's answer is correct, but as you asked "what's the problem with the code" in your comment, the problem with your code is that `cat` normally expects filenames as arugments, and the output of running `cat file1 file2 ...` will be the complete contents of all files being dumped onto your screen, or into any trailing pipelines.

If you use the shell debugging feature, `set -vx` before the loop, you'll see how your $LINE is being passed as a list of files to cat AND of course you can see this by the messages you are getting

```
cat: chr1: No such file or directory
cat: 3392391: No such file or directory
....
```

To fix your code, replace `cat $LINE` with `echo "$LINE"` to keep spaces/tabs as is from your file output OR `echo $LINE` and get one space between each word on LINE.

You solution to print each line by incrementing `$c` as you `head` from your file is super inefficient. You're having to read the file completely for each line of data. While this will work OK for small files, if you apply this technique to a file with thousands of lines, your time to execute will grow exponentially (sorry, not an exact prediction), instead of taking less than 1 sec to process your file, taking 100s or 1,000s of seconds.

(Nice question, I appreciate the sample data. It would also help to include at least a line or two of your expected output.)

I hope this helps.